# relay.dev is not resolving to an IP address - does anyone know what the IP address is

Tags: relayjs, relay

I relay on the documentation at reactjs.org, and it has heaps of links like this:
https://relay.dev/docs/en/experimental/step-by-step
(which is on this page: https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html )

However, relay.dev is not resolving to an IP address right now:

```
C:\>ping relay.dev
Ping request could not find host relay.dev. Please check the name and try again.

C:\>
```

Does anyone have the IP address cached, or know what it is? Or has the site moved to a different domain?

Comment: Disregard this question - my ISP's DNS server is the problem - it is not resolving anything in the relay.dev domain. (ISP is AAPT, DNS server (primary) 192.189.54.17 (secondary) 203.8.183.1. neither DNS servers return anyting when I DIG relay.dev. When I connected to my phone hotspot and used my mobile data, the domain resolves.

Comment: ```nslookup relay.dev
Server:  ns1.aapt.com.au
Address:  203.8.183.1

*** ns1.aapt.com.au can't find relay.dev: Non-existent domain

nslookup relay.dev 203.215.29.191
Server:  dns2.iinet.net.au
Address:  203.215.29.191

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    relay.dev
Addresses:  2600:9000:21ca:e600:1d:c8f8:95c0:93a1
          143.204.160.57
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the IP that I came up with. 13.224.69.33 That IP is simply going to go to the root of the name server (Not the actual website) It is very possible that they have disabled ICMP on their servers making it impossible to ping it. All I simply did was a DNS lookup.

Comment: Thanks Larson, I don't know why my chrome is not resolving that domain - I get ```This site can’t be reached relay.dev’s server IP address could not be found.``` but you're idea to just do a DNS lookup is a simple one, but you're also right is won't let me browse relay.dev with just the IP addresss - I get a 403 error from a 'cloudfront' server.